# How to find out if router supports power over Ethernet (poe)

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, power

I have the Asus RT-N56U router. How do I find out if the router supports POE? A Google search for "asus rt-n56u power over ethernet" did not produce any meaningful results: http://goo.gl/qqNFm

Also do all routers support POE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The specifications do not list PoE so this device does not support PoE.  Most routers will not support PoE.

I would guess more switches support PoE than routers

You can add a PoE injector to most networks that will allow you to connect a  device that requires PoE to a switch or router without PoE. One example is the HP 1-port Power Injector (J9407B)

Comment: PoE is fairly rare in consumer-level products and not even a given on more expensive stuff, so I would always expect it to be called out explicitly.  If you don't see it, it doesn't have it.

Comment: I was coming back to say 'Oh, and you can add a PoE injector' but I see Dave beat me to the punch.